# No emulator images (avds) found. Would like to use genymotion devices

Tags: android, cordova, genymotion

> Error: No emulator images (avds) found.
>
> HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the
>   HAXM device driver
>
> [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
>           You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.
>            [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).

Getting this error while running

```
ionic cordova run android
```

my Genymotion Device is up and running. But cordova is still looking for the devices from the android sdk.

How can I make Cordova to look for Devices from the Genymotion?